# Spanish translation for the term operad?

Tags: terminology, translation-request, mathematical-spanish

I would like to know which is the correct term in Spanish for [operad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory)(s)?

It cannot be *operador*, since that is reserved for operators. I do not see anything online on the topic (there is no Spanish Wikipage for 'operad'). Thanks in advance.

Comment: @got it-thanks Sorry, I should have added that I refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory

Comment: Operad as you quoted is the imperative form of the verb operar.......I mean the noun with a mathematical sense......

Comment: OK.  Sorry.  I had never heard of operad theory.

Comment: This is a made up word in English. There may not be such a thing as a "correct" term for it in another language. Perhaps just use "operad?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All people I know that talk about operads use the word *operad* in Spanish.

Comment: Suárez-Álvarez. So you would then say "teoría de operads" in Spanish?

Comment: I haven't used it much in Spanish conversations, but I'd say "óperad" is more common.

Comment: I would say that, @javier, with the accent as Bruno suggests.

Answer (score 0):

'Factor' is the correct term for the operands in a multiplication but most Spanish speakers who know the term will accept it's use as the general term, mainly due to the rule that has become a saying 'el orden de los factores no altera el resultado', used to argue with someone that it doesn't matter what happened first and what matters is the result.
Most operands have their unique names, such as 'nomio', 'substraendo', 'dividendo', 'divisor', etc.